# Is there a way for eclipse to run a Java program even if there are errors being detected in the project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project with multiple errors in my eclipse workspace. Is there a way to run eclipse and ignore these errors? I need to do this, since the project contains subprojects. Some of these contain errors. I am only working on one of these. However, eclipse won't run the one working on because of the errors in the other project.

Comment: You can comment out the problematic code if it's not needed for what you're trying to do?

Comment: Probably bigger question is: why would you want to do that? For now your question looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse if you attempt to run an app that contains compile errors, you'll see the dialog "Errors exist in required project(s). Proceed with launch?"

If you select 'Proceed' Eclipse will attempt to execute the code. Depending where the errors are, you may be partially successful to execute at least some of the code.

This approach works if there is a compile error in a method that is not called from any other existing code. The existing code will run and execute, and the compile error in a method that is not called doesn't impact the other code.

I believe Eclipse is able to do this by how it incrementally compiles code.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no. Those errors prevent the compiler from generating the output that is actually run.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of error you have. Consider the following example:

```
public class CompileError {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
    
    private method() {
        
    }
}
```

The method is missing a return type and trying to run it will show a warning dialog. But selecting "Proceed" will still run the example and print "Hello World".